# Python webscrape the "next" piece of text in a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am creating a python program which scrapes company financials off a website. I am aware that websites which contain this information makes it particularly difficult to scrape data reliably, and as such, I have met a roadblock.

https://www.reuters.com/companies/3in.L/key-metrics

From this website, I am attempting to scrape the value next to the text "Return on Equity (TTM)". (currently it's 8.86)

I have searched StackOverflow and plenty of other sites. The closest I have got is this:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/companies/3in.L/key-metrics")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.find('span', text='Return on Equity (TTM)').find_next('span').text
print(spans)
```

However, this creates the error:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'`

The line which creates the "spans" variable does not create an error when you remove the find_next bit on the end, instead it prints `None`

I have seen other people successfully use a similar line of code. However, seeing as I am a beginner with BeautifulSoup, there is still clearly a concept I have not grasped.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Hello Chadders! Yes you are correct this returns `None` -> `soup.find('span', text='Return on Equity (TTM)')` & the reason it prints `None` is because it cannot find that particular `span` tag and along with the `text` argument. I think you need to double check the soup if it has those particular data, try printing it out like this `print(soup)` and do a `find` function `ctr+f` on the soup and try to **find** that `span` tag with the `text=Return on Equity (TTM)`

Answer (score 0):

The 'span' you are looking for does not exists. its actually a `div` with the text `Return on Equity (TTM)` inside it. so instead of searching for span, you can search for a div. For example

```
page = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/companies/3in.L/key-metrics")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.find('div', text='Return on Equity(TTM)').find_next('span').text
print(spans)
```

this should return the correct value.

Comment: your code return  value `3.08` but it will be `8.86`!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your speedy reply.

The line of code you provided me does indeed print 3.08, not 8.86. I believe this is because it printed the first entry with the ```class_='MarketsTable-value-FP5ul'```

It seems that I sadly cannot use that to scrape the exact data I need. I am hoping that I can find a way to use the keyword "Return on Equity (TTM)" to find the correct place in the HTML, then print the next piece of text in the website.

Comment: fixed the code. sorry, i was in a hurry and didn't check my answer prev.